# ssh remote access on bash Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssh

I'd like to connect remotely to the Ubuntu bash on my Windows 10.

I've got an answer on port 22 but when it asks for username and password, it says access denied...

[image]

I've already created a user "root" and i've done a "sudo passwd root"

Windows firewall is deactivated (service stopped).

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Stop `ssh server` and `ssh broker` services on Windows to avoid SSH port conflict

Makes below changes in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Then restart ssh server by `sudo service ssh restart`. If you see `could not load host key` error then create host key as below and restart ssh service:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -b 4096 -t rsa
```

Comment: How do you stop ssh server and ssh broker on windows?

Comment: @tmastny click start -> type "services", then you can find them there

Answer (score 2):

First, You need to Stop/Disable Windows 10 SSH Server Broker Services or Change OpenSSH Port.

After that, modify the /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: How do you stop or disable the Windows 10 SSH?

Answer (score 0):

I started having issues after installing VirtualBox with my Bash on Ubuntu on Windows SSH connection. I stopped the VM, uninstalled, and still couldn't authenticate. The user 'Nobody' is correct, the best solution would either to disable the SSH Broker for Windows 10, or just change the port for SSH on the Linux subsystem, which I did, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You must also in most cases add a inbound firewall rule to allow traffic on port 22.. the default setup only allows for inbound traffic using the windows implementation of ssh, therefore not allowing any traffic for the openssh-server. Just follow the instructions above and then add a rule for port 22 inbound in Windows Firewall and you should be set.

Answer (score -1):

Since windows implementation doesn't provide chroot you need to modify the /etc/ssh/sshd_config

> UsePrivilegeSeparation no

Also you will need to create a user using useradd command or so.